# R - implement bootstrap function for paired (mis)matches

Tags: r, sequence, statistics-bootstrap

I have trouble implementing a function in the `boot` library.

The function I want to implement is the following

```
fsyn = function(x) sum( x[1,] == x [2,] )
```

It's a count of the *matches* between two sequences.

My data is a set of sequences such as

```
   id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1  c  a  c  b  c  c  b  d  d   a
2   1  c  d  a  a  c  b  d  a  b   a
3   2  b  d  c  b  b  b  c  d  a   b
4   2  b  a  b  c  b  c  d  b  a   d
```

Something important about these sequences is the fact that they are **paired** by `id`.

I am interested in doing two things, the first is to bootstrap the number of matches by `id` and the second for two random individuals.

The first procedure can be implemented by

```
library(dplyr) 

chid = df$id
# sampling paired sequences # 
wchid = function(chid) which(chid %in% sample(chid, 1))
# the matches function # 
fsyn = function(x) sum( x[1,] == x [2,] ) 
# wrapping the function # 
funcHamC = function(df) df[wchid(chid), -1] %>% fsyn
```

with

```
df %>% funcHamC
```

The second function can simply be written like

```
funcHamR =  function(df) df[sample(df$id, 2), -1] %>% fsyn
df %>% funcHamR
```

However, I have issues using these two functions with `boot`.

```
library(boot)
boot(df, funcHamC, R = 10)
boot(df, funcHamR, R = 10)
```

This isn't working. Any idea ?

**data**

```
df = as.data.frame( t(replicate(20, sample(letters[1:4], 10, T))) ) 
df$id = rep(1:10, 2)
df = df %>% select(id, everything()) %>% arrange(id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boot` function expects two arguments to the `statistic` function—the second being a parameter to specify the sample values to choose. Because you are using your own methods to choose randomly from the data, you should set the `sim` argument to `'parametric'`. This will use the `ran.gen` argument to specify a function to generate random values from the data.

To quote from the help file: "If `ran.gen` is not specified, the default is a function which returns the original `data` in which case all simulation should be included as part of `statistic`."

Save the boot output to variables—such as `C.boot` and `R.boot` and you will find the samples in `C.boot$t` and `R.boot$t`.

```
C.boot <- boot(df, statistic=funcHamC, R = 10, sim='parametric')
R.boot <- boot(df, statistic=funcHamR, R = 10, sim='parametric')
```

You can then obtain the stats you need from the generated values.